# SignalR - mapping unathenticated users to custom id

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I wanted to ask a simple question, and it seems to be one I can't find the answer for. Here's the jist, **I want to use a unique value other than Context.ConnectionId for identifying users**

So, on my hub class I have this method to generate a unique guid, this method is called when I start the connection via my javascript

```
// My hub class
//...

public void GenerateGuid()
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Clients.Caller.myGuid(guid);
}
```

.

```
// My javascript
$.connection.hub.start().done(function(){
    $.connection.chatHub.server.generateGuid();
});

$.connection.chatHub.client.myGuid = function (guid){
    if (docCookies.getItem("guid") === null){
        docCookies.setItem("guid", guid);
    }
}
```

I've also set up a custom implementer of IUserIdProvider (as suggested in these docs https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider to use something other than IPrincipal.Identity.Name (which won't work anyway because my users aren't authenticated))

I think this needs a little modification, as I'm unsure what to return in the case that a guid isn't defined

```
public class MyUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            if (request.Cookies["guid"] != null)
            {
                return request.Cookies["guid"].Value;
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException kex)
        {
            // what to return here?
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        // what to return here?
        return "";                       
    }
}
```

. (This is set up in my Startup.cs so no worries either)

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new MyUserIdProvider());
```

---

**So**, with all of this I suppose there are two questions

1. Am I setting up my `MyUserIdProvider` class in the right way?
2. When I want to access the user's id in my Hub class, how do I access it now? I don't think I can use `Context.ConnectionId` anymore in calls such as this: `return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, [room]);`

Answer (score 0):

`IUserIdProvider.GetUserId` is called upon connection established, before `GenerateGuid` is called. Thus, `cookies` is no use at that phase. You have to setup your own storage based on `request`, for example:

```
public class MyUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    private static IDictionary<string, Guid> _tokens;
    static MyUserIdProvider()
    {
        _tokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Guid>();
    }

    private static string Key(IRequest request)
    {
        var key = request.QueryString["connectionToken"];
        return key;
    }

    public static string UserId(IRequest request)
    {
        return _tokens[Key(request)].ToString();
    }

    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var key = Key(request);
        _tokens[key] = Guid.NewGuid();
        return _tokens[key].ToString();
    }
}
```

With that storage, you can retrieve your user id from `request` in hub method:

```
public void GenerateGuid()
{
    var guid = MyUserIdProvider.UserId(Context.Request);
    Clients.Caller.myGuid(guid);
}
```